# Error in deserializing generic boolean to object in NewtonSoft Json?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net, deserialization

I know this type of question has been asked many times before but I really cannot figure it out. I send this object from a controller:

```
OperationResult<bool>()
{
   IsSuccess = true,
   Result = default,
   Error = null
};
```

I receive this json string in front-end:

```
'{"result":false,"error":null,"isSuccess":true}'
```

And I try to deserialize it like this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OperationResult<R>>(jsonstring);
```

This is the type of object I'm trying to deserialize the json to:

```
    public class OperationResult<R>
    {
        public OperationResult()
        {
        }

        public R Result { get; set; }
        public string Error { get; set; }
        public bool IsSuccess { get; set; } 
    }
```

At deserialization I get this exception:

> Error converting value False to type OperationResult`1[System.Boolean]

This is the inner exception:

> Could not cast or convert from System.Boolean to OperationResult`1[System.Boolean].

The weird thing is that I receive this error only when R is of type boolean.

To be honest I have not tried anything except to change types from boolean to another type to see if the serialization works. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: What is the exact value of `jsonstring`? Are you sure it is the full object and not just a boolean?

Comment: Yes I'm sure it's the full object, this is the jsonstring: '{"result":false,"error":null,"isSucces":true}'

Comment: And do you do `var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OperationResult<bool>>(jsonstring);`?

Comment: Yes, 'jsonstring' variable value is  '{"result":false,"error":null,"isSucces":true}'

Comment: your code works for me, please double check your jsonstring (for testing you can put exact value of jsonstring and see if it raises any error)

Comment: I added this exact value: '{"result":false,"error":null,"isSucces":true}' in the jsonstring variable to be deserealized and I receive the same error...

Comment: Please post the minimal code needed to reproduce this

Comment: you should escape it : "{\"result\":false,\"error\":null,\"isSucces\":true}"

Comment: I did escape it, I will try to repoduce it into a console app and post the full code

Comment: I tried the exact same code on a console app and I could not reproduce it, it works fine. I don't know what the problem could be. I deleted .vs, .obj and .bin obj folders in the solution and rebuild the solution and I have the same issue. I think the issue is the json string but I don't know what it could be.

Comment: Ok, so the issue was that the type of R was actually OperationResult<bool> instead of bool. One simple mistake that cost me entire hours. Thank you guys for the provided help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code in VS, everything works properly, no problem

```
static void Main()
{
    var json="{\"result\":false,\"error\":null,\"isSuccess\":true}";
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OperationResult<bool>>(json);
    json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
}
```

result

```
{
  "Result": false,
  "Error": null,
  "IsSuccess": true
}
```

class

```
public class OperationResult<T>
{
    public T Result { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Actually, there is a problem: in the `json` variable the value of `isSuccess` is `true`, while in the result the corresponding value is `false` (and that's why I am here. If you know why is that so, please let me know).

Comment: @DánielErős IsSucces property of a json string had a typo. It had only one s in the end, instead of two. I just fixed it in my answer

Comment: Great, thank you :) I think the data still do not match: your input is 
`"{\"result\":false,\"error\":null,\"isSuccess\":true}"`  
and the output is 
`{
  "Result": false,
  "Error": null,
  "IsSuccess": false
}`

In my case the cause of the unexpected behaviour was that the propery hadn't had a setter.... so NewtonSoft could not set the actual value to that property, only the default value, which is `false` in case of bool...